# Bash for loop with space separated fields from file

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have following problem, but can not solve it and do not find a solution that fits.

What I want to do:

I have a file **a.txt**. In each line there are 4 space separated fields. *cat a.txt* would give the following output:

```
A0 A1 A2 A2
B0 B1 B2 B3
C0 C1 C2 C3
```

So far, so good. Now each of these things should be a value for an option of a command and I want to run the command for each line the the file like

```
./command -q A0 -w A1 -e A2 -r A3
```

but I do not find a way to do that.

I tried this

```
for i in "`cat a.txt`;do j=($1);./command -q $(j[0]) -w $(j[1]) -e $(j[2]) -r $(j[3]); done
```

but *$(j[0])* includes the whole content of a.txt (so displays the same result as cat) and *$(j[1])* and so on is empty.

Does someone has an idea? (I'm sure someone has ;) )

Comment: Your syntax looks quite a lot like guesswork!

Comment: @TomFenech: Sure, but otherwise it would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't read lines using `for`, or `cat`. As you're using bash, you could read directly into an array, although perhaps it would make more sense to name your variables:

```
while read -r q w e r; do
    ./command -q "$q" -w "$w" -e "$e" -r "$r"
done < a.txt
```

Comment: The double quotes around the variables can be skipped in this case, as there is no playing with `IFS`. Though better quoting too much than too little :)

Comment: @joepd it still protects you in the case that one of the columns in the text file is `*` :)

Comment: Check! Thanks, @Tom Fenech!

Comment: @TomFenech: Thanks a lot! It works, and I do not need to run it some hundred times on my own.